# Apache echarts: how to get smooth line series with big dataset?

Tags: echarts

I'm working with a big dataset, and despite my data not beign strictly increasing, it definitely has phases where it grow and where it shrink.

Took this example as reference: https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=area-time-axis

The problem is that when i try to draw a smooth line, the result is extremly jagged.

How can I have a smooth line like the red one?
I'd also like to show a bettere level of details when zooming on the data, so I can't just remove part of the dataset to make everything smoother.

(sorry for the poor drawing skill):
[image]

Thanks for the help!